# Python/Django library for registering multiple SSO Identity Providers(OpenID Connect)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, single-sign-on, onelogin

I'm working on a project written in Python(Django) and i recently added an SSO option for logging in with OneLogin accounts. There's already support for Microsofts Azure SSO from an earlier feature. 
I'm looking for a library which can somehow register different identity providers(Microsoft, OneLogin, Facebook, etc...) and then wrap the similar login logic into a single class, which would handle all the SSO login attempts mentioned above so i don't have to write a new implementation for each new SSO option added. I don't know if it's relevant but the SSO flow is authorization code flow.
Is there such a library/example?